# Deploy synapse pipeline using JSON file

Tags: azure-synapse

I am trying to create a synapse pipeline using CLI task in Azure DevOps release pipeline. Below is the cli inline script I am using

```
az synapse pipeline create --file @"$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_MyFirstCloudService-CI (4)/drop/synapsepipeline/CopytoADLS.json" --name testpipeline --workspace-name neonatesynapse
```

JSON file I have as simple wait task in the pipeline:

```
{
    "name": "Test Pipeline",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Wait1",
                "type": "Wait",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "waitTimeInSeconds": 1
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

but it always gives below error:

[image]

Any help.

Answer (score 0):

The wait activity looks correct to me according to the MSFT documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-wait-activity

As for the pipeline, I don't think annotation can be null. Please take a look at the pipeline documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/factories/pipelines?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

The default value for annotation is any.